# List.map with two function parameters, in F#

Tags: f#

I came across this syntax:

```
[10.; 11.; 12.]
|> List.map (fun a b -> a * b)
```

in what case does List.map have two parameters (fun a b)?

This is the output in Jupyter Lab:

[image]

Comment: would be nice to know the reason of the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fun example, because it looks confusing and usually doesn't come up in practice, so it caught me off-guard initially.

In short, what happens is you're mapping a list of floats into a list of `float -> float` functions. It's easier to see if you rewrite it as something like this:

```
let results = 
    [10.; 11.; 12.]
    |> List.map (fun a -> (fun b -> a * b))
```

You pass a `float -> float -> float` function as the mapper, and it gets partially applied to the element from the input list. The second argument `b` is not being applied though, so the output of the mapping is a function that takes a float and multiplies it by the partially applied element of the list, and the overall result is a list of `float -> float` functions.

You can then apply those functions to some value like this:

```
results
|> List.map (fun f -> f 2.)
```